# How can I draw Neuro-Fuzzy architecture

Tags: tikz-pgf, neuralnetwork

I try to reproduce the figure below, but I am having difficulties for the connection between inputs x1 and x2 with the first four blocks of "layer 1" et to connect layer 1 with the nodes of "layer 2". Thank you very much.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
    \documentclass[tikz, border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, fit, positioning, quotes}% new libraries


\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  every neuron/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=8mm},
  layer labels/.style={above, align=center},
  cercle/.style={circle,draw,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt}
        }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=16mm, y=16mm, >=stealth]
% neuron nodes with part of labels
\foreach \g  [count=\y] in {1,2,3,4}
\foreach \b/\l in { 0/L}
{
\node[every neuron/.try, neuron \g/.try](n\b\g) at (\b,2.5-\y){}
}
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2}
\foreach \j/\l in { 2/H, 4/S}
{ 
\ifnum\y<3
\node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (n\j\m) at (\j,2.5-\y) {};
\else
\node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (n\j\m) at (\j,2.5-\y) {};
\fi       
}
% neuron labels not included in neuron nodes
%\foreach \l/\k in {I_K/0, H_L/2}
%\node [above] at (n\k2.north) {$\l$};
% inputs
\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2} 
\draw [<-] (n0\i.west) -- ++(-1.1,0) node (in\i) [above, midway] {$x_\l$};
%\node (input) [draw, inner ysep=2mm, yshift=-2mm, fit=(in1) (in2)] {};
% w and L outputs
\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2}
\draw [->] (n4\i.east) -- ++(1.6,0) 
    node (wout\i) [above, midway] {$x_\l$}
   node (Lout\i) [right, draw, minimum size=8mm, label=$L_\i$] {};% Local Model

% output
\node (output) [cercle,right=16mm] at ($(Lout1.east)!0.5!(Lout2.east)$) {};
\draw [->] (output.east) to["$\hat{y}$"] ++(1.1,0);
% neurons interconection
 \foreach \i in {1,2}
 \foreach \j in {1,2}
{
\draw [->] (n0\i) -- (n2\j);
\draw [->] (n2\i) -- (n4\j);
}
\foreach \j [count=\i] in {1,2}
\draw [->] (Lout\i.east) to ["$\hat{y}_\j$"] (output);
% neuron layers labels
\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {1,2,3,4,5} 
\node [layer labels] at (\x*2,2.2) {Couche \\\l};
%\node [layer labels] at (6,2.2)    {Local \\ Model};
%\node [layer labels] at (8,2.2)    {Output \\ Agregation};
% x-fit L-fit conections


   \end{tikzpicture}
   
   \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Where is `x1` and `x2` in your figure that are referenced in the question?  Also, please make sure your code compiles. It would be really helpful if you removed the parts of the diagram that are not relevant to this particular question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I would try to post only the relevant code for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcomen to TeX.SE!!!

An idea drawing almost all elements twice inside a `\foreach` sentence, repeating the top and bottom 'lines' but changing the y-axis direction.

This is my proposal:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset
{
  void/.style={inner sep=0},
  rect/.style={void,rectangle,draw,minimum size=6mm},
  circ/.style={void,circle,   draw,minimum size=6mm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-latex,line cap=round]
% layers
\foreach\ii in {1,...,5}
{
  \ifnum\ii<5
    \draw[-,very thin,red,dashed] (1.5*\ii+0.75,3-0.4*\ii) -- (1.5*\ii+0.75,4);
  \fi
  \node at (1.5*\ii,4) {Layer $\ii$};
}
% nodes
\foreach[count=\ii]\i/\j in {x/1,y/-1}
{
  \begin{scope}[y=\j cm]
    \node       (\i)    at (0,2)               {\strut$\i$}; % x,y
    \node[rect] (A\ii)  at (1.5,5*\j-2*\j*\ii) {$A_\ii$};    % A1,A2
    \node[rect] (B\ii)  at (1.5,-5+4*\ii)      {$B_\ii$};    % B1,B2
    \node[circ] (pi\ii) at (3,1)   {$\pi$};                  % pi
    \node[circ] (N\ii)  at (4.5,1) {$N$};                    % N
    \node[rect] (R\ii)  at (6,1)   {};                       % rectangle
    \node[void] (x\ii)  at ($(R\ii)+(-0.15,0.5)$) [yshift=3*\j mm] {\strut$x$};
    \node[void] (y\ii)  at ($(R\ii) +(0.15,0.5)$) [yshift=3*\j mm] {\strut$y$};
    \node               at (3.75,1.25) {\strut$\omega_\ii$};
    \node               at (5.25,1.25) {\strut$\bar{\omega}_\ii$};
    \node               at (7,0.85)    {\strut$\bar{\omega}_\ii f_\ii$};
  \end{scope}  
}
\node[circ] (sigma) at (7.5,0) {$\Sigma$};
\node[circ] (f)     at (9,0)   {$f$};
% arrows
\foreach\ii in {1,2}
{
  \draw (x.east) -- (A\ii.west);
  \draw (y.east) -- (B\ii.west);
  \draw (A\ii.east) -- (pi\ii);
  \draw (B\ii.east) -- (pi\ii);
  \foreach\k in{1,2}
    \draw (pi\ii) -- (N\k);
  \draw (N\ii) -- (R\ii);
  \draw (x\ii) --++ (0,\ii-1.5);
  \draw (y\ii) --++ (0,\ii-1.5);
  \draw (R\ii) -- (sigma);
}
\draw (sigma) -- (f);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help